# Angular binding inside an inline ckeditor

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm using inline editing with CKEditor, and I'd like to bind an element to an angular scope value.

```
<div contentEditable="true">
   <p>Here is the value: {{testval}}</p>
</div>
```

testval should update in the same manner as it would outside the editor.

To protect this text in the editor, I'd like to do something similar to the [placeholder plugin](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7679/_samples/placeholder.html). In other words I plan to have a placeholder, dynamically displaying the final text rather than just the placeholder.

I've seen several examples of how to bind the entire contents with angular, but not individual elements. I'm still fairly new to both angular and ckeditor, so any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding entirely what you are trying to do. But if the intention is to bind javascript (angular) to an inline WYSIWYG editor, that's probably a bad idea because you leave your website open to XSS and CSRF attacks. But then again, maybe I'm not understanding...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and you are correct; I do want to bind angular to an inline WYSIWYG editor. However, the purpose of the editor is to offer a real time editable structured report (basically a mail merge). i.e. We don't plan on writing the results of the editor back to the database, it will only be used for the users session, then they would print the edited document.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you will need to use a directive for what you want. I might be soewhat off because I'm not completely familiar, but goig by what you've provided, let's assume this example.

**html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div content-editable content="content"></div>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('contentEditable', function() {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            // Assume this will be html content being bound by the controller
            // In the controller you would have:
            // $scope.content = '<div>Hello World</div>'
            content: "=" 
        },
        template: '<div contentEditable="true"><p>Here is the value {{ content }}</p></div>'
    });
```

Still not sure if I completely comprehend, but let me know if I'm getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to bind the HTML text in model to the element. I used ng-bind-html to render what is in the model and I created the directive ck-inline to add the inline feature and bind the model to the changes that happen in the inline editor. This directive requires a ng-bind-html to work and you also need to have ngSanitize added to your module. Add directive ck-inline to your element and

I also use $timeout because I noticed that if I don't the text is rendered and then ckeditor somehow deletes all the values which messes up the model (this does not happen with the non-inline option). Here is the code.

```
yourModule.directive('ckInline', ['$sce', '$timeout', function($sce, $timeout){
    return{
        require : '?ngBindHtml',
        scope:{value:"=ngBindHtml"},
        link : function(scope, elm, attr, ngBindHtml)
        {
            $timeout(function()
            {
                var ck_inline;
                elm.attr("contenteditable", "true");
                CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
                ck_inline = CKEDITOR.inline(elm[0]);

                if (!attr.ngBindHtml)
                    return;

                ck_inline.on('instanceReady', function()
                {
                    ck_inline.setData(elm.html());
                });

                function updateHtml()
                {
                    scope.$apply(function()
                    {
                        scope.value = $sce.trustAsHtml(ck_inline.getData());
                    });
                }


                ck_inline.on('blur', updateHtml);
                ck_inline.on('dataReady', updateHtml);

            }); 
        }
    };
}]);
```